# "Cannot Resolve Constructor Label(java.lang.String)"

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, game-development

Hello I am new to LibGDX and AS. There is an error in my coded:

> "Cannot Resolve Constructor Label(java.lang.String)"

My code is here.

```
countdownLabel = new Label(String.format("%03d", worldTimer)); 
new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(),Color.WHITE);
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Both [`javafx.scene.control.Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html#Label-java.lang.String-) and [`java.awt.Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html#Label-java.lang.String-) has a constructor accepting a single `String` argument, so maybe you imported some *other* `Label` class? --- E.g. [`com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html#constructor.summary), which doesn't have such a constructor *(why did you think it did?)*.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to call [`Label(java.lang.CharSequence text, Label.LabelStyle style)`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html#Label-java.lang.CharSequence-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle-)? If so, change first `);` to `,` and add extra `)` at the end.

Comment: https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario/blob/master/core/src/com/brentaureli/mariobros/Scenes/Hud.java  Is what I was going off of. The line I refered to is line 59.

Answer (score 0):

From [comment to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585237/cannot-resolve-constructor-labeljava-lang-string#comment90136187_51585237):

> [github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario/blob/master/core/src/com/](https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario/blob/master/core/src/com/brentaureli/mariobros/Scenes/Hud.java)… Is what I was going off of. The line I refered to is line 59.

So, compare your statement with line 59:

```
countdownLabel = new Label(String.format("%03d", worldTimer)); new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(),Color.WHITE);   // yours
countdownLabel = new Label(String.format("%03d", worldTimer), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));  // line 59
```

Do you see the difference now?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, really appreciate it, but another question. Now it just says error: cannot find symbol method format(java.lang.String,int) .

Comment: Do you have a class `String` in your package?